# Extrude Polygons for 3D Indoor Mapping...in Mapbox

Tags: html, 3d, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

In reference to this example for mapbox-gl-js... 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-extrusion-floorplan/

When I run this example code with my api  key, I only get the map centered on the "Field Museum of Natural History" without any walls extruded. What am I missing here? The other examples seem to work straight out of copy paste.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.32.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.32.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'>
</div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWtpbmh3YW4iLCJhIjoiY2lwNGYxNDhlMDAwcnZsbTVnY3R0eXo3ZSJ9.XED4AbQBkX8E9qqnwplnWw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-87.61694, 41.86625],
    zoom: 15.99,
    pitch: 40,
    bearing: 20
});

map.on('load', function() {

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'room-extrusion',
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'source': {
            // Geojson Data source used in vector tiles, documented at
            // https://gist.github.com/ryanbaumann/a7d970386ce59d11c16278b90dde094d
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/data/indoor-3d-map.geojson'
        },
        'paint': {
            // See the Mapbox Style Spec for details on property functions
            // https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#types-function
            'fill-extrusion-color': {
                // Get the fill-extrusion-color from the source 'color' property.
                'property': 'color',
                'type': 'identity'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-height': {
                // Get fill-extrusion-height from the source 'height' property.
                'property': 'height',
                'type': 'identity'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-base': {
                // Get fill-extrusion-base from the source 'base_height' property.
                'property': 'base_height',
                'type': 'identity'
            },
            // Make extrusions slightly opaque for see through indoor walls.
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.5
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks Everyone for your help

Comment: It's working for me at http://jsbin.com/vevefalope/edit?html,output
Do you see an errors in the console when you try it?

Comment: Something wrong with your geojson loading I think, host the geojson yourself or copy & paste the json to your code.

Comment: Use `'data': 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/data/indoor-3d-map.geojson'` instead (that is, prefix the URL with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`), and for an explanation, see the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141

Answer (score 2):

This example has a CORS issue

```
Failed to load file:///mapbox-gl-js/assets/indoor-3d-map.geojson: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:
```

A simple workaround is to download the geojson from the [github gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ryanbaumann/a7d970386ce59d11c16278b90dde094d/raw/8c384b4e418670a35dc054ab7da6638ff4073a69/indoor_3D_map_example.geojson) and save it locally in the same directory as your .html file. Then you can add it as a mapbox layer source, e.g:

```
'data': 'indoor_3D_map_example.geojson'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your data and code aren't in the same domain name. You can build a sever, then publish the data and code. You can make it.